# Jesus, Messiah sent by whom?

Tags: messiah

Paul equated Jesus to Melchizedek (Heb 5:6) who was high priest of the "Most High" even before Israel existed. Jesus was sent as messiah by the "God of Israel" (Deut 32:9) for the children of Israel (Math 15:24). However, he is now a messiah for all nations (Acts 15:16, 17), having been sent by "Whom"?

Comment: "Paul equated Jesus to Melchizedek" Where exactly? '... why was there still need for **another** priest to come, one in the **order** of Melchizedek ...' Hebrews 11:7 Paul was well informed as to Melchizedek and the birth of Messiah **some 2000 years later**. To suggest that Paul would be confused as to these things is disingenuous. Non-sensical.

Comment: @davidianwalker - I understand that a comparison was being made between the priesthood of Melchizedek and that of Aaron in Heb 7:11. Kindly enlighten me, within this context, as to a distinctive difference between "equating to Melchizedek"  and "in the order of Melchizedek." I am not well versed in English and shall endeavour to make my questions less non-sensical.

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1**

Jesus was High Priest forever in the ORDER of Melchizedek, Heb 5:6.  Jesus was NOT Melchizedek.

**Point 2**

Jesus claimed numerous times that He had been sent by God the Father; Luke 4:18, (43), John 3:16-18, 5:23, 25, 30, 36, 37, 38, 6:29, 38, 39, 44, 57, 68, 7:16, 18, 33, 8:15, 16, 17, 18, 42, 10:36, 12:49, 14:24, 17:3, 8, 18, 21, 23, 25, 20:21, 1 John 4:14, etc, etc.

**Point 3**

Jesus intended His ministry as Messiah for all people:

- John 1:29, “Behold the Lamb of God who takes away the sin of **the world**.”
- John 3:16, “God so loved **the world** that He gave …”
- John 12:32, “I [Jesus] … will draw **all people** to myself.”
- John 12:47, “… for I did not come to judge **the world** but to save **the world**.”
- Acts 17:30, “God … commands **all people everywhere** to repent.”
- Rom 3:23, 24, “… for **all** have sinned … and **all** are freely forgiven...”
- Rom 5:18, “Therefore, as through one man’s offense judgment came to all people, resulting in condemnation, even so through one Man’s righteous act the free gift came to **all people**, resulting in justification of life.”
- Rom 11:32, “For God has imprisoned everyone in disobedience so that He may show mercy to **all**.”
- 2 Cor 5:14, “…we are convinced that one died for **all**, and therefore **all** died.”
- 2 Cor 5:18, 19, “…God was reconciling **the world** to Himself in Christ …”
- 1 Tim 2:3, 4, “For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour, who desires **all men** to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth.”
- 1 Tim 2:6, “[Jesus Christ] gave Himself as a ransom for **all people**.”
- 1 Tim 4:10, For to this end we toil and strive, because we have our hope set on the living God, who is the Saviour of all people, especially of those who believe.
- Titus 2:11, “For the grace of God appeared bringing salvation to **all people**.”
- Heb 2:9, “But we see Jesus, who was made a little lower than the angels, now crowned with glory and honor because he suffered death, so that by the grace of God he might taste death for **everyone**.”
- 2 Peter 3:9, “The Lord is not slow in keeping his promise, as some understand slowness.  He is patient with you, not wanting anyone to perish, but **everyone** to come to repentance.”
- 1 John 2:2, “He Himself [Jesus] is the propitiation for our sins, and not for ours [Christians to whom John writes] only but also for **the whole world**.”

Answer (score 1):

Q. Paul equated Jesus to Melchizedek (Heb 5:6) who was high priest of the "Most High" even before Israel existed. Jesus was sent as messiah by the "God of Israel" (Deut 32:9) for the children of Israel (Math 15:24). **However, he is now a messiah for all nations (Acts 15:16, 17), having been sent by "Whom"?**

The question begins with the name "Paul," just as do all of Paul's letters, which also contain his credentials as an Apostle; for example:

> [Rom 1:1 NASB95] [1] Paul, a bond-servant of Christ Jesus, called [as] an apostle, set apart for the gospel of God,

> [1Co 1:1 NASB95] [1] Paul, called [as] an apostle of Jesus Christ by the will of God, and Sosthenes our brother,

Paul didn't write "To the Hebrews." In fact, it was not even written by any apostle:

> [Heb 2:3-4 NASB95] [3] how will we escape if we neglect so great a salvation? After it was at the first spoken through the Lord, it was confirmed to us by those who heard, [4] God also testifying with them, both by signs and wonders and by various miracles and by gifts of the Holy Spirit according to His own will.

---

But here's the Hebrews passage, written by an unidentified author:

> [Heb 5:5-6 NASB95] [5] So also Christ did not glorify Himself so as to become a high priest, **but He who said to Him, "YOU ARE MY SON,** TODAY I HAVE BEGOTTEN YOU"; [6] just as He says also in another [passage,] **"YOU ARE A PRIEST FOREVER ACCORDING TO THE ORDER OF MELCHIZEDEK."**

Hebrews says that Christ was not acting on his own, but rather God installed him as the Top Priest, which was the highest position in second Temple Judaism.

If there is more to the question, please send me a comment with clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Paul teaches that Jesus was sent by the God of Israel, who is also the God of all nations. He follows the teaching of Isaiah that - while the LORD was usually referred as Israel's God exclusively in the early history of Israel - he was, in reality, the true God of all people.

Isaiah 2

> In days to come, The mountain of the Lord’s house
> shall be established as the highest mountain
> and raised above the hills. All nations shall stream toward it. 3     Many peoples shall come and say: “Come, let us go up to the Lord’s
> mountain,
> to the house of the God of Jacob, That he may instruct us in his ways,
> and we may walk in his paths.” For from Zion shall go forth instruction,
> and the word of the Lord from Jerusalem. 4 He shall judge between the nations,
> and set terms for many peoples. They shall beat their swords into plowshares
> and their spears into pruning hooks; One nation shall not raise the sword against another,
> nor shall they train for war again.

Comment: I'm now so confused about the translations to "God", "Lord", etc. that I would more appreciate citations that include transliterations of these words from the original texts ...